# Simplify my mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I currently have the following tables with:

```
TABLE klusbonnen_deelnemers:
bonnummer (varchar) - order number
adres (varchar) - order adres
deelnemer (varchar) - user
binnen (date) - date order received
klaar (date) - original order milestone
datum_gereed (date) - date order completed
gereed (varchar) - YES or NO (YES= completed NO= Not yet completed)
datum_factuur (date) - date when user marked order completed (button clicked)
factuur (varchar) - weeknumber order completed
```

One order(bonnummer) can have multiple users (deelnemer) who all have to mark the order "completed" (datum_gereed). Only when ALL users (deelnemer) have marked an order (bonnummer) "completed" (datum_gereed) the order IS "completed".
I am trying to write a query that gives me:
All completed orders (bonnummer) in a given timespan (last month).
However...
The completion date (datum_gereed) should hold the LAST date (as that is the actual total completion date).
The list should have the Order (bonnummer) with the latest "marked completed" date (datum_factuur) on top (sort DESC) (of course only when all users (deelnemer) have completed the order (all users(deelnemers) having gereed="YES")

So far i have this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT tbl1.bonnummer AS 'KLUSBONNUMMER', tbl1.adres AS 'ADRES',
        tbl1.binnen AS 'BINNENGEKOMEN OP', tbl1.klaar AS 'ORIGINELE STREEFDATUM',
        tbl1.datum_gereed AS 'GEREEDGEKOMEN OP', tbl1.factuur AS 'WEEKNUMMER'
    FROM  klusbonnen_deelnemers AS tbl1
    INNER JOIN  
      ( SELECT  tbl2.bonnummer
            FROM  klusbonnen_deelnemers AS tbl2
            WHERE  tbl2.bonnummer NOT IN (
                SELECT  tbl3.bonnummer
                    FROM  klusbonnen_deelnemers AS tbl3
                    WHERE  tbl3.gereed = 'NEE')
      ) AS tbl4 ON tbl1.bonnummer = tbl4.bonnummer
    INNER JOIN  
      ( SELECT  bonnummer, MAX(datum_gereed) AS 'MAXDATUM'
            FROM  klusbonnen_deelnemers
            GROUP BY  bonnummer
      ) MAXFILTER ON tbl1.bonnummer = MAXFILTER.bonnummer
      AND  tbl1.datum_gereed = MAXFILTER.MAXDATUM
    WHERE  tbl1.datum_factuur BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND NOW()
    ORDER BY  tbl1.bonnummer DESC
```

This query DOES work, however i think this can be done in a much simpler way.
On top of that the query only works in my navicat editor. Calling this query on my "live" website gives an error (subquery in WHERE clause...) (i do have all login correct as other queries DO work).

Anyone out there who can help (simplify) this query? Thx...

Comment: `not in` can be dangerous with nullability. consider `not exists`

Comment: How do you know how many people have been associated with a project... so that you know how many approvals to look for?  Do all orders have the same number of people approving or will all orders by default have a no for all users until they finally approve?

Comment: The number of people associated with a project varies. When they get appointed to a project a new row is added for every user defaulting to no.

Comment: `TABLE klusbonnen_deelnemers:` Please post real DDL; no shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

this part:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT tbl2.bonnummer
FROM klusbonnen_deelnemers AS tbl2
WHERE tbl2.bonnummer NOT IN 
(SELECT tbl3.bonnummer 
FROM klusbonnen_deelnemers AS tbl3
WHERE tbl3.gereed = 'NEE')) AS tbl4
ON tbl1.bonnummer = tbl4.bonnummer
```

seems like useless. try to use `gereed <> 'NEE'` in the "very-bottom"-`WHERE`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        kd.bonnummer    AS 'KLUSBONNUMMER',
        kd.adres        AS 'ADRES',
        kd.binnen       AS 'BINNENGEKOMEN OP',
        kd.klaar        AS 'ORIGINELE STREEFDATUM',
        kd.datum_gereed AS 'GEREEDGEKOMEN OP',
        kd.factuur      AS 'WEEKNUMMER'
    FROM klusbonnen_deelnemers AS kd
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT bonnummer, MAX(datum_gereed) AS 'MAXDATUM'
            FROM klusbonnen_deelnemers 
            GROUP BY bonnummer
        ) AS MAXFILTER 
        ON (kd.bonnummer = MAXFILTER.bonnummer AND kd.datum_gereed = MAXFILTER.MAXDATUM)
    WHERE
        kd.gereed <> 'NEE' 
        kd.datum_factuur BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND NOW()
    ORDER BY 
        kd.bonnummer DESC
```